# redis.createClient() doesn't work in docker

Tags: javascript, docker, redis, redisclient

I want to use redis-image in docker-hub.

so, i make docker-compose.yml file like this

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  backend:
    container_name: test-server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ".:/app"
      - "/app/node_modules"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - redis
  redis:
      image: redis
      command: redis-server --port 6379
      container_name: redis
      hostname: redis
      labels:
        - "name=redis"
        - "mode=standalone"
      ports:
        - 6379:6379
```

For docker internal connection, I found some few answers in stackoverflow

> [fail to link redis container to node.js container in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28020852/fail-to-link-redis-container-to-node-js-container-in-docker/28031085#28031085)

so, I `redis.createClient("redis://0.0.0.0:6739");` like this

when, I build docker image. and run docker

In this container `Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379`

Initially, I think the url error, but i change to `redis://localhost:6378`(just change port)

I got same error, like this
`Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379`

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754304/redis-connection-to-127-0-0-16379-failed-connect-econnrefused

Comment: You need to use the Redis container's Compose name `redis` as a hostname.  Neither 0.0.0.0 ("listen on all interfaces") nor 127.0.0.1/localhost ("this container") will work.  You can safely remove the `container_name:` and `hostname:` options from your Compose setup, they're not required for this connectivity.